# Opaque text but transparent background for Powershell/Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, powershell

I would like to just have the text and header bar visible while I'm using the command line. I've tried Console, but like Powershell, adjusting transparency settings affects the text as well. Is there any software/option for having the background be completely transparent while the text remains opaque?

Answer (score 1):

Try using ConEmu.  You can set window transparency and background image transparency separately.  It also has a lot of other useful features and is very customizable.

[image: Screenshot of ConEmu transparent window]

[ConEmu Website](http://conemu.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing [Glass](https://glass.codeplex.com/)
as it will work on both cmd and Powershell. Last version was released last year but being so simple it might just work fine.

To install, download the zip, unzip it, go to *Release* folder and run the exe file.

Comment: This answer was marked as low quality. Perhaps see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).